# About python class __init__ and Decorators

Tags: python, properties, decorator, init

when I learn 'property' of python, To my surprise, the output is not as same as expected.The code illustrated below:

```
class HideX(object):
    def __init__(self,x):
        self.x = x
    def get_x(self):
        return ~self.__x
    def set_x(self,x):
        assert isinstance(x,int),\
        '"x" must be an integer!'
        self.__x = ~x
    x = property(get_x, set_x)


    inst = HideX(20)
    #inst.x = 20#
```

when it executes `inst = HideX(20)`. I think it will call `__init__(self,x)` so the instruction `self.x = x`will be executed. The problem occurs. I think it will not call `x = property(get_x, set_x)`because `self.x` is in the body of class (it is in the top of the class).I've always thought
only in the outside of class (as show in #..#)can we access `x = property(get_x, set_x)` am I wrong? can you understand  what I mean?

sovled:
After repeated tests, I  found amazedly that when we execute`inst = HideX(20)`, the code `x = property(get_x, set_x)`
will be  called in the first place ,not the '**init**(self,x)'.Totally beyond my expectation!!!(In the java ,when we create an instance,the init() of the class will be first called i think ,maybe i am wrong)

(1)Can you give me an explanation of the intrinsic mechanism?  I am a green hand,Thanks for your patience.

the code  below is the  Segment I copy from :

```
class HideXX(object):
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x

    @property
    def x():
        def fget(self):
            return ~self.__x

        def fset(self,x):
            assert isinstance(x,int),\
            '"x" must be an integer!'
            self.__x = ~x

        return locals()

    #x = property(**x())
inst =  HideXX(1)
```

But it can not run correctly
the error code is :

```
File "<string>", line 21, in <module>
File "<string>", line 4, in __init__
AttributeError: can't set attribute
```

(2)Is the book wrong ?? When I removed @property and add the code 'x = property(**x())' It works!!!

can you explain the reason for me ? thanks very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your first question , the answer is simple, x is an attribute of the class (not the object/instance of the class) , it would be evaluated when the class gets defined (not when its object is created).

An Example to show this -

```
>>> class CA:
...     y = print("Hello")
...     def __init__(self):
...             print("Blah")
...
Hello
>>> c = CA()
Blah
```

As you can see the value of `y` gets calculated when the class is defined, its the same with all functions in the class, they get defined when the class gets defined, but they are evaluated only when the function gets called.

Also, using the @property is not same as `property(**x())` , when you do the later , `**x()` resolves to -

```
{'fget': <function HideXX.x.<locals>.fget at 0x00943B28>, 'fset': <function HideXX.x.<locals>.fset at 0x00943CD8>}
```

And then these positional arguments are used for setting the `getter` and `setter` for the property `x` , whereas the `@property` annotation is used to define the getter for property x.

Comment: thanks for your patience. Yr first answer  is pretty helpful for me, and the second answer is also clear. But the example above( @property def x():...) is copied from the book named Core ‘Python Programming,2nd Edition’ . Is the book wrong? or do I make something wrong?

Comment: The example where you are getting the error ? Is that directly copied from the book?

Comment: yes, I copy from <Core Python Programming,2nd Edition>  about page 422 there is pdf in network [https://code.google.com/p/ownerpress/source/browse/trunk/startZine/books/Core.Python.Programming,2nd.Edition.pdf?r=9975]

Comment: Yes, I believe the book is a little bit wrong, in the second case, since we are using `decorators` instead of static class variables, we would have to do `HideXX.x = 10` or set `HideXX.x` to some arbitary number before we can creates instances for it.

Comment: Also, if you believe an answer has answered your questions satisfactorily, please do remember to accept them (by clicking on the tick mark on the left side of the answer) . It would help the community.